# How to quit applications black screen with white borders?

Tags: windows-8

While playing Dynasty Warriors 8 Empire, I accidentally pressed the *off* button of my laptop. Afterwards turned on and logged in, it's like that although musics still play.

- function keys work, like volume up/down. It'll appear on-screen
- mouse disappeared
- pressing keys on keyboard seems to have effect (hypothesised through the sounds) but it just don't appear on-screen

[image: black screen with white borders]

My laptop screen is within the white borders, black part outside the white borders is just background of this photo.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you bring up task manager (via `shift+esc`) and end the process that way? Note that if you cannot see the process list, you may still be able to end the task (**nb attempt at your own risk as this may end other tasks**) - press `D` (for Dynasty Warriors process title), then `alt+e` (for end task)

Comment: I can't see, mentioned in the 3rd bullet. Is there a good solution without forcefully ending it?

Comment: I saw the third bullet- if the keyboard is *probably* working you may want to try what I described. However there was an error so I will write it up as an answer (comments can't be edited after 10 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

This back screen issue can happen surprisingly often. If the keyboard still works as you suspect, you can assume that Windows is still responding to input. You could then use `Task Manager` to kill the game's process:

**1)** bring up `Task Manager` via `ctrl+shift+esc` (hold `Ctrl` and `Shift`, then press `Esc`)

**2)** highlight the program's process by typing letters that match the title (in this case type `dynas` to match 'Dynasty Warriors')

**3)** end the process via `alt+e` (for `End task`)

Do note that you are doing this at your own risk- if you had a process that had the title "Dynamic DNS Updater" (*hypothetically*), typing `dyna` might highlight that process instead. If you type to slowly (`d`... `y`) you may instead jump to a title beginning with 'y' (*"Yahoo Answers - How do I quit a frozen game?"... hypothetically*).

---

This has happened to me often enough that I occasionally kill the offending process rather than let it churn away in the hope it will start drawing the screen and responding to input again.